# Вывод сгенерированных чисел

Tags: php

Есть функция, которая генерирует 4 числа и выводит их через запятую. Например, *13, 15, 1, 8,*.
Как можно убрать последнюю запятую?

```
function random($min, $max) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        echo mt_rand($min, $max) . ", ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможны несколько вариантов, например, собрать все числа, потом их вывести на экран:

```
function random($min, $max) {
    $values = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
        array_push($values, mt_rand($min, $max));
    }
    echo implode(', ', $values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так : )

```
function random($min, $max) {
    printf(
        '%d, %d, %d, %d',
        mt_rand($min, $max),
        mt_rand($min, $max),
        mt_rand($min, $max),
        mt_rand($min, $max)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант: Генерируй 3 числа, а 4 без запятой

Answer (score 0):

```
function random($min, $max) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        echo mt_rand($min, $max) . ($i < 3 ? ',' : '');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Просто обрежь последний символ:

```
function random($min, $max) {
    for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
        $a .= mt_rand($min, $max).", ";
    }
    echo substr($a, 0, -1);
}
```

Comment: Тогда стоит обрезать два последних символа.